# Export and import data from parse server

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I am trying to export and import my database from parse server into / from to xls and csv files. I am using bitnami Parse server with dashboard 1.0.25. Where ever i search it either states Parse has been closed or this functionality is not there on parse server. My question is is there any way to do it without of much hassle thank you and should i keep on using Parse server as it is open source or switch to another as mentioned on many website that many developers are moving to other databases such as mongodb or Firebase etc.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just call the data from server in your model and export it locally. Why you want to export files on server.

Answer (score 0):

In the shell use `mongodump` or `psql yourdatabasename < db.psql` in case of postgres.